How do you combine multiple column pairs into one table (with zeros for missing values)?
I have many column pairs (mass spectral data) that I want to combine into one array with the zeros for the missing rows.
I have something like this:
column pairs



Mass
10
Mass
11
Mass
12
Mass
13




80
22005
81
30908
81
46532
80
22259


81
33306
82
47792
82
97559
81
42002


82
27314
84
1315498
83
35698
82
233130


83
27204
85
110460
84
2391605
84
6892485


84
644196
86
25905
86
51365
85
502763


85
54723
87
31240
87
34415
86
37660


86
28384
88
22801
88
21819
87
40078


87
32212
90
24878
89
25326
88
39850


88
38615
91
36830
90
30998
89
44535


89
13155
92
27189
92
28916
90
38188


90
20406
93
29146
93
19224
92
31855




95
22505
94
31359
93
18951




96
18047
95
22533
94
37879




97
97665
96
28238
95
38750






97
132143
96
16119






98
18459
97
171050






99
17121
98
23113






101
9579
99
34733






102
235454
100
23821






103
25700
101
28792






104
17415
102
442859






105
28789
103
28505






106
16005
104
14448






107
17534
106
22950






108
24548
107
25922








108
29475








109
15177








110
123036








111
30295








112
18465








113
52162








114
19906








115
64107








116
60852



...and I want to have something like this:
combined array



Mass
10
11
12
13




80
22005
0
0
22259


81
33306
30908
46532
42002


82
27314
47792
97559
233130


83
27204
0
35698
0


84
644196
1315498
2391605
6892485


85
54723
110460
0
502763


86
28384
25905
51365
37660


87
32212
31240
34415
40078


88
38615
22801
21819
39850


89
13155
0
25326
44535


90
20406
24878
30998
38188


91
0
36830
0
0


92
0
27189
28916
31855


93
0
29146
19224
18951


95
0
22505
22533
38750


96
0
18047
28238
16119


97
0
97665
132143
171050


94
0
0
31359
37879


98
0
0
18459
23113


99
0
0
17121
34733


101
0
0
9579
28792


102
0
0
235454
442859


103
0
0
25700
28505


104
0
0
17415
14448


105
0
0
28789
0


106
0
0
16005
22950


107
0
0
17534
25922


108
0
0
24548
29475


100
0
0
0
23821


109
0
0
0
15177


110
0
0
0
123036


111
0
0
0
30295


112
0
0
0
18465


113
0
0
0
52162


114
0
0
0
19906


115
0
0
0
64107


116
0
0
0
60852



I tried using the pivot column, but it did not work. Some TOCOL usage may be an option.

Transform Data
=LET(data,A1:H11,na,0,
    s,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/2,,,2),
    sh,TAKE(data,1),
    dh,HSTACK(TAKE(sh,,1),CHOOSECOLS(sh,s+1)),
    sd,DROP(data,1),
    drl,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(sd,s),1))),
    dd,DROP(REDUCE("",s,LAMBDA(rr,c,
        HSTACK(rr,XLOOKUP(drl,CHOOSECOLS(sd,c),
            CHOOSECOLS(sd,c+1),na)))),,1),
    VSTACK(dh,HSTACK(drl,dd)))

The Variables
s   - {1;3;5;7}
s+1 - {2;4;6;8}
sh  - A1:H1
sd  - A2:H11
dh  - J1:N1
drl - J2:J17
dd  - K2:N17





Mass
11
Mass
12
Mass
13
Mass
14




21
5381
24
6004
24
3391
19
4477


14
5939
21
8932
26
7270
13
7440


23
1855
25
7809


15
7419


25
8175
23
9400


17
1035




19
3749


24
6855




17
4518
14
4876
21
3810




28
9400
13
8150




16
5418


23
3158




18
4676


21
9707




11
4962


10
9057
20
6584




Thank you very much for your reply! I tried to use your formula with your MWE, but I got the error "There's a problem with this formula." I am sure I need to do something differently. Please help!)))

It could mean that your list separator is a semicolon (;). Replace all commas (,) with it (;).

Unfortunately, it does not work for me:
LET(data,A1:H11,na,0,
{1;3;5;7},SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/2,,,2),
A1:H1,TAKE(data,1),
J1:N1,HSTACK(TAKE(A1:H1,,1),CHOOSECOLS(A1:H1,{2;4;6;8})),
A2:H11,DROP(data,1),
J2:J17,SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(A2:H11,{1;3;5;7}),1))),
K2:N17,DROP(REDUCE("",{1;3;5;7},LAMBDA(rr,c,
HSTACK(rr,XLOOKUP(J2:J17,CHOOSECOLS(A2:H11,c),
CHOOSECOLS(A2:H11,c+1),na)))),,1),
VSTACK(J1:N1,HSTACK(J2:J17,K2:N17)))
With semicolons also does not work...

You have to replace only the commas with semicolons. "The Variables" shows just what each variable represents.

Hello,
I found that my Excel have problems with the c and r letter as well. So I have used this, but still without result:
=LET(data;A1:H11;na;0;
{1;3;5;7};SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data)/2;;;2);
A1:H1;TAKE(data;1);
J1:N1;HSTACK(TAKE(A1:H1;;1);CHOOSECOLS(A1:H1;{2;4;6;8}));
A2:H11;DROP(data;1);
J2:J17;SORT(UNIQUE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS(A2:H11;{1;3;5;7});1)));
K2:N17;DROP(REDUCE("";{1;3;5;7};LAMBDA(yy;u;
HSTACK(yy;XLOOKUP(J2:J17;CHOOSECOLS(A2:H11;u);
CHOOSECOLS(A2:H11;u+1);na))));;1);
VSTACK(J1:N1;HSTACK(J2:J17;K2:N17)))

Here is another way using MAKEARRAY() --> not using heavy resource functions for data manipulations.


• Formula used in cell J1
=LET(
     _Data, A1:H35,
     _Header, TAKE(_Data,1),
     _Rest, DROP(_Data,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(TOCOL(FILTER(_Rest,_Header=TAKE(_Header,,1)),1,1)),
     _Output, MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq),MAX(SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(_Rest)/2)),LAMBDA(r,c,
     IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(_Uniq,r,),CHOOSECOLS(_Rest,c*2-{1,0}),2,0),0))),
     VSTACK(UNIQUE(_Header,1), HSTACK(_Uniq,_Output)))



I found that my Excel have problems with letters r and c, so I have used this:
=LET(
_Data; A1:H35;
_Header; TAKE(_Data;1);
_Rest; DROP(_Data;1);
_Uniq; UNIQUE(TOCOL(FILTER(_Rest;_Header=TAKE(_Header;;1));1;1));
_Output; MAKEARRAY(ROWS(_Uniq);MAX(SEQUENCE(;COLUMNS(_Rest)/2));LAMBDA(u;y;
IFNA(VLOOKUP(INDEX(_Uniq;u;);CHOOSECOLS(_Rest;y*2-{1;0});2;0);0)));
VSTACK(UNIQUE(_Header;1); HSTACK(_Uniq;_Output)))
However, no result: it returns error for FILTER function.

@lemann all the given solutions works on my end, its because of your excel version which doesn't supports.

Thank you very much for your help! I will try to update my Excel and try your solutions. Please, let me know which version of Excel did you use.

@lemann MS365. You can use the web version of excel as well click here

For fun, my recursive alternative, should be fast:

Formula in J1:
=LET(r,A1:H35,h,A1:H1,n,UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFERROR(IFS(h>"0",r&"")*1,"Mass"))),x,LAMBDA(f,i,z,IF(i=COLUMNS(r),z,f(f,i+2,HSTACK(z,VLOOKUP(n,DROP(r,,i),2,0))))),IFNA(x(x,,n),))


Thank you for your help, however no result: it returns error "invalid name". I have used this:
=LET(y;A1:H35;h;A1:H1;n;UNIQUE(TOCOL(IFERROR(IFS(h>"0";y&"")*1;"Mass")));x;LAMBDA(f;i;u;IF(i=COLUMNS(y);u;f(f;i+2;HSTACK(u;VLOOKUP(n;DROP(y;;i);2;0)))));IFNA(x(x;;n);))

It works fine for me. I use the exact same syntax with semi-colon too. @lemann. What version of Excel you running?

Microsoft Excel 2019 MSO (16.0.10406.20006) 32-Bit

@lemann all the given solutions works on my end, its because of your excel version which doesn't supports.
